# What is a good approach to clustering multi-dimensional data?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-science, pca

I created a k-means clustering for clustering data based on 1 multidimentional feature i.e. 24-hour power usage by customer for many customers, but I'd like to figure out a good way to take data which hypothetically comes from matches played within a game for a player and tries to predict the win probability.

It would be something like:

```
Player A
Match 1
Match 2
.
.
.
Match N
```

And each match would have stats of differing dimensions for that player such as the player's X/Y coordinates at a given time, time a score was made by the player, and such. Example, the X/Y would have data points based on the match length, while scores could be anywhere between 0 and X, while other values might only have 1 dimension such as difference in skill ranking for the match.

I want to take all of the matches of the player and cluster them based on the features.

My idea to approach this is to cluster each multi-dimensional feature of the matches to summarize them into a cluster, then represent that entire feature for the match with a cluster number.

I would repeat this process for all of the features which are multi-dimensional until the row for each match is a vector of scalar values and then run one last cluster on this summarized view to try to see if wins and losses end up in distinctive clusters, and based on the similarity of the current game being played with the clustered match data, calculate the similarity to other clusters and assign a probability on whether it is likely going to become a win or a loss.

This seems like a decent approach, but there are a few problems that make me want to see if there is a better way

One of the key issues I'm seeing is that building model seems very slow - I'd want to run PCA and calculate the best number of components to use for each feature for each player, and also run a separate calculation to determine the best number of clusters to assign for each feature/player when I am clustering those individual features. I think hypothetically scaling this out over thousands to millions of players with trillions of matches would take an extremely long time to do this computation as well as update the model with new data, features, and/or players.

So my question to all of you ML engineers/data scientists is how is my approach to this problem?

Would you use the same method and just allocate a ton of hardware to build the model quickly, or is there some better/more efficient method which I've missed in order to cluster this type of data?

Comment: Kindly be reminded that SO is about *specific coding* questions, and not a design, recommendation, or discussion forum; you question is way too broad for here.

Answer (score 0):

It is a completely random approach.

Just calling a bunch of functions just because you've used them once and they sound cool never was a good idea.

Instead , you first should formalize your *problem*. What are you trying to do?

You appear to want to predict wins vs. losses. That is **classification** not clustering. Secondly, k-means minimizes the sum-of-squares. Does it actually !ake sense to minimize this on your data? I doubt so. Last, you begin to be concerned about scaling something to huge data, which does not even work yet...